# Spring aop - String property is null in an aspect class

Tags: spring, spring-aop

In an aspect can we declare a property? If yes why do I get a null value for name property in method?

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ProtectResourceOperationAspect  {

    private String name = "my name";

    @AfterReturning("execution(* org.jxs.mm.service..*(..)) && @annotation(auth) && args(user, theme, ..)")
    public void updateThemeLock(ProtectResourceUploadAuth auth, User user, Theme theme) {
        System.out.println(name);//null
    }
}
```